# Puppet working with nested hashes and arrays

Tags: puppet

I want to checkout several SVN projects and I need to be able to choose the directory names for each branch or trunk.

Now I want to check out the SVN project called svn_name in the folder service_dir and inside that folder I want to create a trunk folder and a branches folder with all branches.

---SVN folder

--------branches

--------------- branch1_name

--------------- branch2_name

------- trunk_name

I have the following structure of my hash

```
$hash = { 
         'svn_name' => { 
             service_dir  => 'directory_name',
                   branch => [ { branch => '0.1', branch_dir => 'branch1_name'}, 
                               { branch => '0.2', branch_dir => 'branch2_name'} ],
                    trunk => {  service_dir => 'trunk_name'},
        }
}
```

Now I use create_resources with the hash and my defined type to create the necessary folders and checkout the working copies.

The problem is that I'm unable to iterate through my branch array, I don't know how to access the values inside the hash.

```
define test (
  $service_dir,
  $branch,
  $trunk
){
  file { "/xxx/${service_dir}/branches/${branch[branch_dir]}":
    ensure => present
  }
}
```

How do I access the variables? Or is there a much easier way to accomplish this? I don't want to use vcsrepo or similar modules because I'm still new to Puppet and need to practice.

Edit1: I probably don't need the hash for the trunk, right? trunk => 'trunk_name' should be enough

Answer (score 1):

To help you achieving your goal faster I'd highly recommend using the *vcsrepo* type provided by PuppetLabs on [github](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-vcsrepo) or [puppet forge](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/vcsrepo). This wraps most common VCS tools, including subversion. Just to prevent you from reinventing the wheel.

About your puppet syntax question, I've adapted the example from the [manual](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_datatypes.html#indexing-1) slightly to fit your problem:

```
$foo = "key"

$myhash = [ { key       => "some value 0",
              other_key => "some other value 0" },
            { key       => "some value 1",
              other_key => "some other value 1" } ]
notice( $myhash[0][$foo] )
notice( $myhash[1][$foo] )
```

Testing it:

```
% puppet apply foo.pp
Notice: Scope(Class[main]): some value 0
Notice: Scope(Class[main]): some value 1
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.08 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the each function (I think it was implemented in puppet 4.6) to iterate through hashes and arrays to define resources.

```
$hash = {
  'svn_name' => {
      service_dir  => 'directory_name',
      branch => [
          { branch => '0.1', branch_dir => 'branch1_name'},
          { branch => '0.2', branch_dir => 'branch2_name'} ],
      trunk => {  service_dir => 'trunk_name'},
  }
}

$hash['svn_name']['branch'].each | $branch | {
  notify { "TestNotify ${branch[branch]}\\${branch[branch_dir]}" : }
}
```

I only showed doing one 'each' function, but you do an each function inside of an each function, but it wouldn't make sense with your scenario.